# Twilio: Disable Beep in Record function does not work

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api

I am using Python and the Twilio Voice API (Response). Whenever I use the Beep attribute, the console shows: "Attribute 'playbeep' is not allowed to appear in element 'Record'." and Twilio is actually ignoring the attribute at all. Here is my code:

response = VoiceResponse()

response.record(action="/record/handle-recording", playBeep="false")

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

With the [Twilio Python library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python), the attributes are translated to snake case to match the language style. So, you need to use `play_beep` instead of `playBeep`. I'd also use a boolean rather than a string.

```
response = VoiceResponse()
response.record(action="/record/handle-recording", play_beep=false)
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Perfect, that was a great help!